# Unable to package a python script which with matplotlib imported using pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a [python script](http://codepad.org/KJRU3xOY) using pyinstaller.

- os:windows7 32
- python:2.7.9
- pyinstaller:2.0

My code contains the following imports:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    #Created Time: 2015/9/8 18:48:04

    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
        FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas)
    from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
    from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
    from matplotlib import rcParams
    rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['SimHei']
    rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

run command in CMD:

> python pyinstaller.py matplot.py -D -w

output:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 86, in main
    run_build(opts, spec_file)
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 50, in run_build
    PyInstaller.build.main(spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1625, in main
    build(specfile, buildpath)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\build.py", line 1582, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\matplot\matplot.spec", line 5, in <module>
    hookspath=None)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\build.py", line 389, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\build.py", line 315, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\build.py", line 475, in assemble
    importTracker.analyze_script(script)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 205, in analy
ze_script
    return self.analyze_r('__main__')
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 98, in analyz
e_r
    newnms = self.analyze_one(name, nm, imptyp, level)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 159, in analy
ze_one
    mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "F:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\depend\imptracker.py", line 256, in doimp
ort
    hooks = __import__('PyInstaller.hooks', globals(), locals(), [hookmodnm])
TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is py2exe involved in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on python3.4 pyqt5 pyinstaller-python3
THX!